# Regular expression to extract a value at end of a set of parameters with Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have the following POST data:

`dynamicfields=%7B%221%22%3A%7B%22ID%22%3A1%2C%22Name%22%3A%22Email+Address%22%2C%22Value%22%3A%221%40d.com%22%7D%2C%222%22%3A%7B%22ID%22%3A2%2C%22Name%22%3A%22First+Name%22%2C%22Value%22%3A%22coldplay1%22%7D%2C%225%22%3A%7B%22ID%22%3A5%2C%22Name%22%3A%22Contact+No%22%2C%22Value%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%226%22%3A%7B%22ID%22%3A6%2C%22Name%22%3A%22Gender%22%2C%22Value%22%3A%22Male%22%7D%2C%224%22%3A%7B%22ID%22%3A4%2C%22Name%22%3A%22Date+of+birth%22%2C%22Value%22%3A%2201%2F1%2F2011%22%7D%2C%223%22%3A%7B%22ID%22%3A3%2C%22Name%22%3A%22Last+Name%22%2C%22Value%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%227%22%3A%7B%22ID%22%3A7%2C%22Name%22%3A%22Country%22%2C%22Value%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%228%22%3A%7B%22ID%22%3A8%2C%22Name%22%3A%22Unique+Identity+Type%22%2C%22Value%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%229%22%3A%7B%22ID%22%3A9%2C%22Name%22%3A%22Unique+Identity+Number%22%2C%22Value%22%3A%22%22%7D%7D&f1=1%40d.com&f2=coldplay1&f5=&f6=Male&v6=&month=01&ddlDate=1&v4=&f4=01%2F1%2F2011&f3=&f7=&f8=&f9=&sk=16dcc29ca6320a4583aa32fa0c5035f7eb9a`

and i have to extract:

```
&sk=16dcc29ca6320a4583aa32fa0c5035f7eb9a.
```

The value for `SK` is session ID which keeps changing in each iteration.
Tried using RegExtractor but didn't worked.
RegEx: `&sk=(.*?)` or `&sk=(.+?)` both are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this expression:

- &sk=(.+?)\b

\b indicates end of word if sk is always at end

Comment: Thanks. I got it worked some other way. Even your ReEx works correctly.